# Past tense in the sentence 'If you don't, you failed.'

Tags: past-tense, clauses

This is the sentence from a [TED Speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MBaFL7sCb8&t=421s).

You could watch it at 1:52.

> . . . if you do that everything will fall into place and if you don’t you **failed**.

Why is she saying 'failed'?
Isn't it supposed to be just 'will fail'?
 Is she trying to show something different nuance?

Comment: Could you please leave a link to the talk you're referring to?

Comment: @M.A.R. I'm sorry I forgot to add the link. Thank you for letting me know. :) I just put it.

Comment: If you don't do the thing she is talking about, you have failed. I think she said: "**You've** failed."

Comment: @Willow is right. She says "you've failed", which is a normal use of perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a clearer way to say what the TED speaker was saying:

'If you do that, then everything will fall into place, but if you don't, you will *have* failed.'

Yes, literally, she means 'will fail', but the correct English expression is 'you HAVE failed', as the speaker said. (you've = you have).

From a learning point of view, it is more correct to say 'you *will* have failed'. The logic behind this is that if a certain action is not carried out, then the person not only WILL fail, but *once* they've failed, they would say 'I *have* failed', so, looking into the future, they '**will** *have* failed'.

There's no nuance: you can think of it as 'will fail', just keep in mind that you should say it as 'will have failed': it's just a strange thing about the English language.